# Why do we use Concept&Constraint

Tags: c++, c++20

I don't really understand why C++20 provides such a feature like that. I need someone to point out how to use this feature gracefully.
Here is an example:

```
template<typename T>
concept LessCompareable=requires(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
      {lhs<rhs}->bool;
};
```

Now I've defined a concept.
Then I'll constraint a function template like this:
(well, let's name it *comp*, in fact it just like `std::min`)

```
template<typename T>
const T& comp(const T& a , const T& b) requires LessCompareable<T>
{return a<b?a:b;}
```

So the problem is if you call this like

```
std::thread a,b;
cout<<comp(a,b);
```

**complie error occured**

but if we don't use constraint, CE will occur, too.

So that makes me puzzled, both of them have CE, then why I should use constraints?

I think if I want to clean up error messages, I can use SFINAE.

Comment: [This suggests](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) you will get easier to understand compile errors, rather than the current mess of errors deep within template library code.

Comment: @KenY-N Yes, I've seen it on *cppreference*, but I still don't know why it will be easier to understand. Of course, the CEs are much less, but I think it is easy to find complie errors while using template library code, too. Maybe there are some complicated CEs that I don't know.    And cannot be denied that this is a benefit of this feature, this comment is really good. But I wonder if there is some bigger good aspects, and I want to learn this feature well at the same time.

Comment: Then just take my word for it that an (implied) constraint error in a 20-deep instantiation stack can be ugly and hard to read. Especially when the mistake caused the compiler to choose an unexpected overload around level 12.

Comment: @Useless Thanks, I see.

Comment: Asked long time ago, I had't understand the significance of replacing some type check based on SFINAE at that time. But now I understood that it does a vital part in cleaning up complier error messages.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The purpose of constraints is to allow you to specify pre-conditions on operations using built-in language constructs. Those pre-conditions could be checked by the compiler and either:

1. You'll get a clear error message.
2. The overload will not be considered in overload resolution (yes, one more way to do SFINAE).

The error messages are nice to have, but the new pre-condition checks for #2 are the real meat of this. What you'd need to do before C++20 to obtain the same effect is something like this:

```
template<typename T,
         std::enable_if_t<has_less_than_op<T>::value, int> = 0>
const T& comp(const T& a , const T& b) 
{return a<b?a:b;}
```

It's clunky and cumbersome, and you need to have foreknowledge about SFINAE techniques to understand why someone would ever write something like that. It's extremely expert friendly. Templates already have that power, but that is an historical coincidence. Concepts (lite) and constraints give the ability to express the same thing in a much more natural way.

Compare the above with your OP or this:

```
template<LessCompareable T>
const T& comp(const T& a , const T& b)
{return a<b?a:b;}
```

Which of the alternatives expresses things clearer? Not the old technique, I'd say.

Comment: Does that mean I shouldn't use std::enable_if_T in type_traits anymore?

Comment: @JohnDing - You can still use it, and given how complex C++ is, there may yet be a need for it that I'm unaware of. This is meant to replace the "hackish" ways we were using it for SFINAE and such.

Comment: Concepts make it also much easier to define constraints. Up to C++17 one had to the detection idiom or other hacks do define classes like `has_less_than_op<T>`. With concepts one can easy state what members and functions one expects by using `requires` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

One important feature of concept in contrast to existing methods is shrinking the compile errors to definition time and instantiation time. Currently all the errors are generated at the instantiation of the template and it is hard to detect whether the template definition is ill-formed and never compiles or prepared parameters are inappropriate. Main goal of concept is to separate the two types of errors.