# What are C++ concepts really useful for?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I think the template C++ system is really powerful.

Now, "concepts" are being introduced and the main reason I found so far is just to allow the compiler to issue shorter/more meaningful messages when a template is misused.

Why not just fix the compiler "verbosity" and let programmers use templates in the usual "duck typing" way?

In addition, having to define concepts introduce a new kind of errors when they don't reflect correctly the intended way of use.

EDIT:

Have we to assume that the answer to the related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668120/about-constraints-and-concepts) is effectively affirming that concepts are only to improve compiler's error messages? Not that clear, IMHO.

Also, not answering if concepts are really necessary to get clearer error messages and why can't we get better messages not using concepts.

Comment: Concepts are *the* way to name semantic constraints, how else do you think the compiler is supposed to know what is the name of the error?

Comment: @PasserBy Well, just asking. If I write "a + b" and a is an apple and b is a rabbit, is it that difficult for the compiler just say "operation + can't be used with apples and rabbits"?

Comment: @cibercitizen1 Sure, but wouldn't it be better if we could just say "a and b needs to both be fruits or both animals or whatever other complex constraint I have" and the compiler can just see that there's an error as soon as you pass the parameters in, instead of 12 layers down into 12 other template functions where the `operator+` is evetually used? Have you seen the 5 pages of template errors with all the "required from here: code/line reference" outputs templates can give? Additionally, giving a better error message is just one of the many advantages of having concepts.

Comment: It could be that you are trying to sum apples and rabbits. It could be that the rabbit is accidently converted from something else. It could be the `operator+` was not found by name lookup. It could be that apples and rabbits should be both converted to money, but the conversion is broken. All of them are legal, how is the compiler supposed to know which one you mean?

Comment: @PasserBy Well, I don't want the compiler to solve it. Just to say ONE message: "I don't have any + for an apple and a rabbit".  Just with that simple message, I will figure out what's wrong ("Oh, I actually want apple and rabbits converted to money, Oh I thought I had defined a + for apples and rabbits,  Oh, a is not supposed to be a rabbit, ... and so on ... )